# Odd behavior of fs.readdirSync

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, synchronization, pm2

I use `nodejs` 5.5.0, and `pm2` 1.0.1. I run the script with:

```
npm start
```

And in package.json, it is defined as:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "pm2 start bin/www --watch"
},
```

I have this simple script that returns a list of videos and it works:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    const fs = require('fs');
    shows = fs.readdirSync(`public/videos`);
    res.render('index', shows);
});

module.exports = router;
```

But I observed something interesting... If I make the below modification, it no longer works, and returns an empty list:

```
//shows = fs.readdirSync(`public/videos`);
res.render('index', fs.readdirSync(`public/videos`));
```

To make it more interesting, the following works:

```
shows = fs.readdirSync(`public/videos`);
res.render('index', fs.readdirSync(`public/videos`));
```

It almost seems to me, if there is some sort of delay or caching, fs.readdirSync works fine, but not if it is called straight on the same line.

Did I miss something simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out and it was actually something really simple that I missed. The name of the **local** variable is **significant**.

In case 3, although shows is not explicitly passed in, it is actually visible to the page being rendered using swig.

If I do not want to introduce the variable shows, I could have done the following and it works:

```
res.render('index', {shows: fs.readdirSync('public/videos')});
```

Answer (score 1):

Somebody correct me if I'm wrong..

But I believe it is because `res.render` has a third argument that you don't see which is `callback` [noted here](https://github.com/expressjs/connect-render/blob/master/lib/render.js#L77)

So when you create the variable in your first example, you block until you get the variable, and then your render the template with the variables available at run time.

But in your second example, you're passing in that option, but `res.render`'s callback is calling before `readdirSync` can finish populating.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this and I really appreciate it. Think I figured out what exactly happened.